# How 64bit FastCGI library can be built within 32bit Linux Mint?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, 64-bit, fastcgi

I am able to build 32bit FastCGI library in 32bit Linux Mint using this sequence:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

But how should I change files in order to build 64 version? I've already installed multilib for gcc and g++.

Comment: could you please eleborate more about your environment? are you trying to build 64bit binary on 32bit linux?

Comment: yes, I have 32bit Linux Mint 13. I need to create 64bit library which will be used in 64bit Gentoo. The file 'configure' is made by Autoconf 2.52

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with your gcc compiler, but you can try provide -m64 option for compilation. Something like CFLAGS="-m64" ./configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to compile 64 bit applications on a 32 bit machine, *but* you will not be able to run them.

I beleive all you would have to do is pass `CPPFLAGS+=-m64` to the compile line and voila. The `configure.sh` probably takes optional parameters for you to specify the build environment manually.

Comment: *Kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it?* All that software I build and then run on my Continuous Integration build agent...